# Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0 - where is the error?

Tags: sql-server, ado.net, connection-string, azure-sql-database

This is my connection string as entered on the Configure page in the Azure portal on an Azure Website:

```
Server=tcp:ghywv7yvsd.database.windows.net,1433;Database=ABCD;User ID=abcd@ghywv7yvsd;Password=AppleJuice1;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;
```

The connection string is taken from the Azure Sql Dashboard and I changed only the User Id and Password fields.

I first created on the Azure Sql server with:

```
CREATE LOGIN abcd WITH password='AppleJuice1'    --On Master database
CREATE USER abcd FROM LOGIN abcd               --On ABCD database
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner','abcd'
```

Is the error (see Subject line) caused by some error in the connection string or wrong setting up of login/user on the database?

---

Parts of the stack trace:

> [ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not
>   conform to specification starting at index 0.]
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.GetKeyValuePair(String
>   connectionString, Int32 currentPosition, StringBuilder buffer, Boolean
>   useOdbcRules, String& keyname, String& keyvalue) +5360365
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable
>   parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable
>   synonyms, Boolean firstKey) +124
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString,
>   Hashtable synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules) +95
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String
>   connectionString) +59

Separately I forced the connection string to print with:

```
throw new Exception(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);
```

and this is what I got on the page:

> Server=tcp:ghywv7yvsd.database.windows.net,1433;Database=ABCD;User
>   ID=abcd@ghywv7yvsd;Password=AppleJuice1;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection
>   Timeout=30

Comment: When do you get this error?

Comment: When.the MVC app was trying to first access it.  The database is initially totally empty.  The MVC project uses code-first approach and should create the database.  This is the standard MVC template project from VS2013 and using the Identity Framework.

Comment: Hi Old Geezer, Is the database ABCD already created? Or are you trying to create it in your code? Your connection string looks fine to me. Also have you tried doing things like a simple select statement?

Comment: Your connection string and login/user creation looks fine. Can you share code the C# code where you are actually connecting to SQL DB?